# Reading From a text file and search to see if it is a cow and the highest costpermonth and print it to screen

Tags: c#

hey i am doing BIT(bachelor of information technology) and I have read from a text file that has 20 lines and it is split by ',' what I am trying to do is get the and I am trying to find the cow that has the most milk in the switch menu I have done the search by ID number but I just can't get my head around the cow that produces the most milk from that text file

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Livestock[] animals = new Livestock[20];
        int counter = 0;
        string myLine;
        string[] words;
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("S:/BIT694/livestock.txt");

        while ((myLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            words = myLine.Split(',');
            int ID = int.Parse(words[0]);
            string LivestockType = words[1];
            int YearBorn = int.Parse(words[2]);
            double CostPerMonth = double.Parse(words[3]);
            double CostOfVaccination = double.Parse(words[4]);
            double AmountMilk = double.Parse(words[5]);

            if (LivestockType == "Cow")
            {
                Cow newCow = new Cow(ID, "Cow", YearBorn, CostPerMonth, CostOfVaccination, AmountMilk);
                animals[counter] = newCow;
            }
            else if (LivestockType == "Goat")
            {
                Goat newGoat = new Goat(ID, "Goat", YearBorn, CostPerMonth, CostOfVaccination, AmountMilk);
                animals[counter] = newGoat;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        int choice;

        for (;;)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------Menu--------"); // The menue Title
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("1) Display livestock information by ID"); // Display the livestock by ID number
                Console.WriteLine("2) Display cow that produced the most milk"); // Displays the cow that porduces the most milk
                Console.WriteLine("3) Display goat that produced the least amount of milk"); // Displays the goat that produces the least amount of milk
                Console.WriteLine("4) Calculate farm profit"); // Calculates the farm profit
                Console.WriteLine("5) Display unprofitable livestock"); // Displays the unprofitable livestock
                Console.WriteLine("0) Exit"); // Exits the program
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Enter an option: ");

                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (choice < 0 || choice > 5);

             if (choice == 0) break;

             Console.WriteLine("\n");

             switch(choice)
             {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("Enter livestock ID: ");
                    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    // Find animal by id
                    Livestock livestock = null;
                    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        if(animals[i].iD == input)
                        {
                            livestock = animals[i];     // Get the animal
                        }
                    }

                    if(livestock != null)
                    {
                        livestock.displayInfo();
                    } else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ID not found"); // Invaild ID
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cow that produced the most Milk:");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Goat that produced the least amount of milk:");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Calculateion of farm profit:");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Livestock that are not profitable:");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("The Option that you have entered is invalid please try again");

                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Livestock
{
    private int ID; //ID Number of livestock
    private string LivestockType; //Value is either "Cow" or "Goat"
    private int YearBorn; //Year of birth with format YYYY (i.e. 2014)
    private double CostPerMonth; //The cost per month
    private double CostOfVaccination; //Annual vaccination cost
    private double AmountMilk; //The amount of milk produced per day in liters

    public int iD { get { return ID; } }
    public string livestockType { get { return LivestockType; } }
    public double costPerMonth { get { return CostPerMonth; } }

    public Livestock(int ID, string LivestockType,int YearBorn,double CostPerMonth,double CostOfVaccination,double AmountMilk)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.LivestockType = LivestockType;
        this.YearBorn = YearBorn;
        this.CostPerMonth = CostPerMonth;
        this.CostOfVaccination = CostOfVaccination;
        this.AmountMilk = AmountMilk;

    }

    public void displayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(LivestockType);
        Console.WriteLine("ID:\t\t\t {0}",iD);
        Console.WriteLine("Year Born:\t\t {0}",YearBorn);
        Console.WriteLine("Cost Per Month\t\t ${0}",CostPerMonth);
        Console.WriteLine("Cost Of Vaccination:\t ${0}",CostOfVaccination);
        Console.WriteLine("Milk Per Day:\t\t {0}liters",AmountMilk);
        return;

    }


}

class Cow : Livestock
{
    public Cow(int ID, string LivestockType, int YearBorn, double CostPerMonth, double CostOfVaccination, double AmountMilk) : base(ID, LivestockType, YearBorn, CostPerMonth, CostOfVaccination, AmountMilk)
    {     

    }
}
```

you will see case 1 is done I just need to do the same for case 2.

Comment: This is not a code provider site, if you were able to code `Case 1` why can't you code `Case 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `AmountMilk` with a `private` access specifier and it doesn't have a getter.

Assuming you are using C# 3 or greater, you can use [automatic properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), so that you can define properties like

```
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

The compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's `get` and `set` accessors.

```
Livestock maxCow = animals.Where(animal => animal.LivestockType == "Cow").OrderByDescending(animal => animal.AmountMilk).FirstOrDefault();
```

The above code uses a Linq expression,

```
animals.Where(animal => animal.LivestockType == "Cow"
```

gets all the animals of LiveStockType `"Cow"` on which we do a descending sort based on the `AmountMilk` property and `FirstOrDefault` returns the first element in the sorted collection, if there is no such element it returns `null`.

The full code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Livestock[] animals = new Livestock[20];
            int counter = 0;
            string myLine;
            string[] words;
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("S:/BIT694/livestock.txt");

            while ((myLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                words = myLine.Split(',');
                int ID = int.Parse(words[0]);
                string LivestockType = words[1];
                int YearBorn = int.Parse(words[2]);
                double CostPerMonth = double.Parse(words[3]);
                double CostOfVaccination = double.Parse(words[4]);
                double AmountMilk = double.Parse(words[5]);

                if (LivestockType == "Cow")
                {
                    Cow newCow = new Cow(ID, "Cow", YearBorn, CostPerMonth, CostOfVaccination, AmountMilk);
                    animals[counter] = newCow;
                }
                else if (LivestockType == "Goat")
                {
                    Goat newGoat = new Goat(ID, "Goat", YearBorn, CostPerMonth, CostOfVaccination, AmountMilk);
                    animals[counter] = newGoat;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            int choice;

            for (;;)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("--------Menu--------"); // The menue Title
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("1) Display livestock information by ID"); // Display the livestock by ID number
                    Console.WriteLine("2) Display cow that produced the most milk"); // Displays the cow that porduces the most milk
                    Console.WriteLine("3) Display goat that produced the least amount of milk"); // Displays the goat that produces the least amount of milk
                    Console.WriteLine("4) Calculate farm profit"); // Calculates the farm profit
                    Console.WriteLine("5) Display unprofitable livestock"); // Displays the unprofitable livestock
                    Console.WriteLine("0) Exit"); // Exits the program
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter an option: ");

                    choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                } while (choice < 0 || choice > 5);

                if (choice == 0) break;

                Console.WriteLine("\n");

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Enter livestock ID: ");
                        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Livestock livestock = animals.Where(animal => animal.ID == input).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                        if (livestock != null)
                        {
                            livestock.displayInfo();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ID not found"); // Invaild ID
                        }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Cow that produced the most Milk:");
                        Livestock maxCow = animals.Where(animal => animal.LivestockType == "Cow").OrderByDescending(animal => animal.AmountMilk).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (maxCow != null)
                            maxCow.displayInfo();
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("No cow");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Goat that produced the least amount of milk:");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Calculateion of farm profit:");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Livestock that are not profitable:");
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("The Option that you have entered is invalid please try again");

                        break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Livestock
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } //ID Number of livestock
        public string LivestockType {get; set;} //Value is either "Cow" or "Goat"
        public int YearBorn  { get; set; } //Year of birth with format YYYY (i.e. 2014)
        public double CostPerMonth  { get; set; }//The cost per month
        public double CostOfVaccination { get; set; } //Annual vaccination cost
        public double AmountMilk { get; set; } //The amount of milk produced per day in liters

        public Livestock(int ID, string LivestockType, int YearBorn, double CostPerMonth, double CostOfVaccination, double AmountMilk)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.LivestockType = LivestockType;
            this.YearBorn = YearBorn;
            this.CostPerMonth = CostPerMonth;
            this.CostOfVaccination = CostOfVaccination;
            this.AmountMilk = AmountMilk;

        }

        public void displayInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(LivestockType);
            Console.WriteLine("ID:\t\t\t {0}", iD);
            Console.WriteLine("Year Born:\t\t {0}", YearBorn);
            Console.WriteLine("Cost Per Month\t\t ${0}", CostPerMonth);
            Console.WriteLine("Cost Of Vaccination:\t ${0}", CostOfVaccination);
            Console.WriteLine("Milk Per Day:\t\t {0}liters", AmountMilk);
            return;
        }
    }
```

[LINQ reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)

Comment: i have tried that and it wasn't working i have updated my code

Comment: is the goat one the same just change the => to =< and change the maxCow to minGoat

Comment: @P.Hohipa In the code above, `=>` is part of syntax to declare [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions), it is not to be confused with greater than or equal to operator (`>=`).

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide your "Cow" class I have to do some fantasy-code inbetween.

```
 case 2:
    Cow cowWithBestMilk; //Used to save the cow with the most milk production

    ///Lets Search
    for( int i = 0; i < animals.Count; ++i)
    {
      //check lifestock, but only cows
      if( LivestockType == "Cow" )
      {
        //Amount to check of my livestock
        double livestockMilk = animals[i].getMilkAmount(); //<-- fantasy code, you have to acces here the AmountMilk of your cow
       if(cowWithBestMilk != null)
       {
          //check if the cow from the lifestock got more milk than the other cow
          if( livestockMilk > cowWithBestMilk.getMilkAmount() ) //<-- you can use >= instead of > if you want to have the last cow with the same amount
          {
             cowWithBestMilk = animals[i]; 
          }
       }
       else
       {
         //there was no other cow until now
         cowWithBestMilk = animals[i];
       }

      } //if type cow

    } //for

    if( cowWithBestMilk != null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Cow that produced the most Milk:" + cowWithBestMilk.getHerIdAsString() ); //<--fantasy code here
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Who let the cows out?");
    }

    break;
```

So what are we doing there.
First we declare cowWithBestMilk and in the loop we iterate over all livestock and overwrite our cowWithBestMilk when in the iteration over the livestock a cow is found AND it produced a higher amount of milk then our cow(WithBestMilk) from the previous iteration.

At the end when doing the console output, the case that our livestock didn't had any cow is covered by an alternate output.

I hope this helps a little bit.